# How to separate a combined column, but with incongruent data

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I'm preparing for a new job where I'll be receiving data submissions in varying quality, often times dates/chars/etc are combined together nonsensically and must be separated before analysis. Thinking ahead of how might this be solved.

Using a fictitious example below, I combined region, rep, and product together.

`file['combine'] = file['Region'] + file['Sales Rep'] + file['Product']`

```
    Shift Region Sales Rep  Product  Cost per  Units Sold              combine
0       3   East  Shirlene   Pencil         5          71   EastShirlenePencil
1       3  South  Anderson   Folder        17          69  SouthAndersonFolder
2       3   West    Shelli   Folder        17         185     WestShelliFolder
3       3  South    Damion   Binder        30         159    SouthDamionBinder
4       3   West  Shirlene  Stapler        25          41  WestShirleneStapler
```

Assuming no other data, the question is, how can the 'combine' column be split up?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In a real example, would you know the 3 original values that make up the combined? Would you know the options for them - like Region is one of 4 options, will that always be the case and be the case for all columns? In this example, you capitalize the first letter of each word, and so your combined thing could be separated by capital letters; would that be the case?

Comment: @scotscotmcc The actual use case is health plan data submissions where date, patient name, serial number, illness code, and facility name are often crammed into one cell. Go figure. However, the data's logic is predictable, and some of the components are limited and consistent (i.e. facility name and illness code) however, length varies due to patient and facility names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want space between the strings, you can do:

```py
df["combine"] = df[["Region", "Sales Rep", "Product"]].apply(" ".join, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Shift Region Sales Rep  Product  Cost per  Units Sold                combine
0      3   East  Shirlene   Pencil         5          71   East Shirlene Pencil
1      3  South  Anderson   Folder        17          69  South Anderson Folder
2      3   West    Shelli   Folder        17         185     West Shelli Folder
3      3  South    Damion   Binder        30         159    South Damion Binder
4      3   West  Shirlene  Stapler        25          41  West Shirlene Stapler
```

---

Or: if you want to split the already combined string:

```py
import re

df["separated"] = df["combine"].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"[A-Z][^A-Z]*", x))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Shift Region Sales Rep  Product  Cost per  Units Sold              combine                  separated
0      3   East  Shirlene   Pencil         5          71   EastShirlenePencil   [East, Shirlene, Pencil]
1      3  South  Anderson   Folder        17          69  SouthAndersonFolder  [South, Anderson, Folder]
2      3   West    Shelli   Folder        17         185     WestShelliFolder     [West, Shelli, Folder]
3      3  South    Damion   Binder        30         159    SouthDamionBinder    [South, Damion, Binder]
4      3   West  Shirlene  Stapler        25          41  WestShirleneStapler  [West, Shirlene, Stapler]
```

Comment: Andrej, I sincerely appreciate your input. Thank you. However, I may have been unclear. The non 'combine' columns are for context. Assume those columns are not there.

Comment: At a loss of words, that was amazing. Thank you Andrej

Comment: AndrejKesely, your findall is splitting based on finding capital letters, is that right? @Ben, will that work? Are your illness codes going to start with capitals (as opposed to numbers or other characters) or have multiple capitals? Or a facility might be 'Memorial Hospital', with two different capital words?

Comment: @scotscotmcc In most cases, yes, but not always. Nevertheless, the forms Andrej introduced new learning dimensions for using regular expressions. Nonetheless, thank you for following up Scot, I appreciate the consideration.